# Should i redraw the GUI after change?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, matrix

I have built a GUI displaying a matrix. It looks much like in excel where you have labels on the first row and first column. The cells contains either 1 or 0.

There's a JComboBox below the matrix. I can select an item from the JComboBox and click a button "add". This adds an extra row to the matrix with the JComboBox item as its name. My question is how i should handle expanding this.

Is it a good idea to have a method that redraws the whole window? Or should i try and just redraw the part that's been changed?

I thought of having a method like `updateWindow()` that could be used both for initiating the window and updating it if i make changes.

Comment: What tool kit are using? AWT, Swing, SWT?

Comment: I use Swing JFrame, JPanel, JButton, JLabel and so on. There are two awt imports: java.awt.Component and java.awt.GridLayout. I'm not very experienced with these, so I'm not sure what they mean or what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to have a method that redraws the whole window? Or should i try and just redraw the part that's been changed?

It depends on what's in your window.

If you're drawing on a `JPanel`, by overriding the `paintComponent` method, redraw the entire `JPanel`.  It's not worth the effort to try and redraw a part of a `JPanel`.

If you have a window made up of many `JPanel`s, you can redraw just the `JPanel` with the changes.

> I thought of having a method like `updateWindow()` that could be used both for initiating the window and updating it if i make changes.

It's generally a good idea to create methods to perform specific GUI tasks.  I'd have separate `initializeWindow` and `updateWindow` methods for my own sanity.  I usually separate the initialization of my GUI from the update of my GUI.

Read this excellent article, [Sudoku Solver Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196), to get an idea of how to put together a Swing GUI.

Answer (score 1):

When you add components to a container, you will be invalidating that container's layout.  This will automatically trigger a repaint, so the question becomes moot.

The real question becomes why?

Instead of messing about with labels and fields, you should just simply use a `JTable`.  Check out [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

This is optimized for performance, so if you're really concerned, this should provide a better solution, so long as you are firing the correct events to the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're finding yourself performance bound, I see no real reason not to redraw the entire window; sure there will be a performance hit but it should be negligible and your source will be simpler and easier to maintain. However, if you're finding yourself pressed for performance, I would suggest looking into implementing a "dirty rectangles" method of redrawing (i.e. your second approach).